# how to detect file if exist in python

Tags: python, file, detect

how can i detect if a specifics files exist in directory ?
example: 
i want to detect if (.txt) files exist in directory (dir)
i tried with this :

```
import os.path
from os import path

def main():

   print ("file exist:"+str(path.exists('guru99.txt')))
   print ("File exists:" + str(path.exists('career.guru99.txt')))
   print ("directory exists:" + str(path.exists('myDirectory')))

if __name__== "__main__":
   main()
```

but all this functions you must to insert the complete file name with format(.txt)

Thank you !

Comment: you're already checking if files exist? do you want to check if ANY .txt files exist?

Comment: You are not using an absolute path, so are only testing if a given filename exists *in the current working directory*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from glob import glob
files = glob('*.txt') 
print(len(files)) # will return the number of .txt files in the dir
print(files) # will return all the .txt files in the dir
```

Comment: This doesn't check if a *specific file* exists.

Comment: @DerekEden: I did read it. Don't assume the question's English is perfect.

Comment: well his code already checks for specific files, and the second part of the question says if .txt files...

Comment: thank you , it's exactly what i want <3

Answer (score 1):

to check if a specific file exists:

```
import os
os.path.exists(path_to_file)
```

will return True if it exists, False if not

to check if ANY .txt files exist:

```
import glob
    if glob.glob(path_to_files_'*.txt'):
        print('exists')
    else:
        print('doesnt')
```